# Working with Pandas DataFrame: I want to add missing year in timestamp column which includes month/day and time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have timestamps but the year is missing. Currently the column is object/series and I want to convert it to datetime format using 'pd.to_datetime' but since the year is missing I am getting an error message. How can I insert the year "2020" to the timestamps shown below:

```
DateTime
1    01/01  00:02:00
2    01/01  00:04:00
...
262799   12/31  23:58:00
262800   12/31  24:00:00
```

I would like to have this output but I do not know how to get it:

```
DateTime
1    2020/01/01  00:02:00
2    2020/01/01  00:04:00
....
262800   2020/12/31  24:00:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string concatenation:

```
df['DateTime'] = '2020/' + df['DateTime']
```

Or to datetime:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime('2020/' + df['DateTime'], dayfirst=False)
```